# HtmlUnit asNormalizedText() returns empty string

Tags: java, web-scraping, xpath, htmlunit

I have this code:

```
HtmlPage rowPage = ...
String address1 = ((HtmlDivision)rowPage.getFirstByXPath("//div[contains(@class, 'client_address1')]")).asXml();
System.out.println("address1 = " + address1);
String address1_2 = ((HtmlDivision)rowPage.getFirstByXPath("//div[contains(@class, 'client_address1')]")).asNormalizedText();
System.out.println("address1_2 = " + address1_2);
```

and my output is:

```
address1 = <div class="client_address1 clientRow">
  123 Somewhere ln
</div>

address1_2 =
```

I expect `asNormalizedText()` to return `123 Somewhere ln`. What circumstances would cause `asNormalizedText` to return nothing?

Comment: Should it be `//div[contains(@class, 'client_address1')]/text()`?

Comment: @LMC good solution. So I lean on the XPath to get the text, not the HtmlUnit methods. It works (had to change `HtmlDivision` to `DomText` but I got it). Leave an answer and I'll give you your points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit more specific XPath would help

```
//div[contains(@class, 'client_address1')]/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

> What circumstances would cause asNormalizedText to return nothing?

From the javadoc:

Returns a normalized textual representation of this element that represents
what **would be visible to the user if this page was shown in a web browser**.

Please check the css class - maybe the style hides the text.